# Print awk's current new line character

Tags: linux, awk

How can I find what new line character is in my file when using `awk`?

I know the default is `\n` but this is what manual says. I want to see it with my own eyes.

I have just started learning `awk` and how to change the output record separator but first I want to see what the actual ORS is. The first 7 chapters of `awk` manual didn't address this.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { printf(ORS) }'`

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't use Awk for this, but rather **od** (octal dump)

For example, here is a simple text file created on a linux system with vi:

```
lizard:~tmp$ cat foo
This is a sentence.
```

Here is the output of od:

```
lizard:~tmp$ od -a foo
0000000   T   h   i   s  sp   i   s  sp   a  sp   s   e   n   t   e   n
0000020   c   e   .  nl  nl
0000025
```

Notice that this file contains a blank line below the sentence, as there are two **nl**'s  (New Line = Line Feed = \n). "sp" represents a space character. If I dump a similar file created on a Windows system it would probably look like this:

```
lizard:~tmp$ od -a foo-dos
0000000   T   h   i   s  sp   i   s  sp   a  sp   s   e   n   t   e   n
0000020   c   e   .  cr  nl  cr  nl
0000027
```

This is exactly the same file, but created on a Windows system.
DOS/Windows files us \r\n (Carriage Return Line Feed) for text file line endings.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect it by, e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "%s", ORS }' | od -c
```